# how to compute the prediction standard error of zero-inflated count data regression using R

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, standard-error, zero-inflation

I have count data and explanatory variables. I can use the `pscl` R package to do a ZINB regression thanks to `zeroinfl`.
I'd like to get access to the mean response and more importantly to the *standard error of the prediction* or some kind of *variance related information of the prediction*. I understand that with the following code, I am estimating the parameters of my regression and computing standard error of the estimation(not the one I am looking for).

```
library(pscl)
zinb <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/fish.csv")

m1 <- zeroinfl(count ~ child + camper | persons,
  data = zinb, dist = "negbin")
summary(m1)


Call:
zeroinfl(formula = count ~ child + camper | persons, data = zinb, dist = "negbin")

Pearson residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.5861 -0.4617 -0.3886 -0.1974 18.0135 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.3710     0.2561   5.353 8.64e-08 ***
child        -1.5153     0.1956  -7.747 9.41e-15 ***
camper1       0.8791     0.2693   3.265   0.0011 ** 
Log(theta)   -0.9854     0.1760  -5.600 2.14e-08 ***

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   1.6031     0.8365   1.916   0.0553 .
persons      -1.6666     0.6793  -2.453   0.0142 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta = 0.3733 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 60 
Log-likelihood: -432.9 on 6 Df
```

Now that my model is trained, I can have the mean response with:

```
predict(m1, type='response')
```

but I've also seen that by changing the `type` parameter I can even get access to the expected probabilities given the exogeneous variables with

```
predict(m1, type='prob')
```

My understanding is that with those probabilities, I have access to the whole predicted distribution and not only the mean so I can compute the variance and confidence intervals. Is my understanding correct and Does it make statistical sense to use those probabilities to compute a standard errors and build CIs around the response means ?

I've looked at a dozen of posts and none uses `type='prob'` and they tend to propose bootstrap instead (eg. #58002334 of StackOverflow and #31113 of StackExchange) so I am confused.